# How to parse a response which can be text or JSON or XML

Tags: java, xml, json

I am trying to connect to a website. After While authentication is successful, I get the following response:

```
{"code": "OK", 
 "data": {"session_id": "apimanager@taurusseo.com:EdiPNoBS2iYxOsAF9e2ceMbk"}, 
 "user": "apimanager@taurusseo.com"}
```

What is the quick and easy way to parse through the (pure text) response given above?

Also, if the response is a JSON object, then how do I parse through the response, preferably using GSON library? I just want to use a library that is supported by Google App Engine for Java and GSON is one of those.

Finally, if a response analogous to the above is an XML response, then do I have to model a struct that resembles the response above? Again, is there a quick and easy way to get the response and parse through it, preferably using XML RPC Client? Again, I just want to use a library that is supported by Google App Engine for Java. XML RPC client is just a suggestion, if you can suggest something better then kindly do so.

Comment: I'm confused -- you want to convert a json object to a string, and then parse that string?

Comment: @MattFenwick- I just want to correctly parse through a response, the response can be plain text/json/xml-- what I suggested about converting json to string and then parsing that string, is one of the possible ways to parse through json responses...Sorry if that confused you.. I am suitably editing the question to remove that suggestion...

Comment: the content-type header from the response should help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am confused as to why you would get back different data types of responses for the same request.  However, you should be able to inspect the Content-Type header of the response, to determine if you should parse it as JSON or XML.  As you already mentioned, you could use a library such as Gson to handle the response as JSON, or one of the build-in XML APIs (e.g. JAXP) to handle the response as XML.

Comment: @ziesemer- I am only going to get back a plain text response for the code that I am currently working on, however I have to work with XML and JSON responses also in future, hence I asked about all 3 types in the same question...

Comment: For each request you make, you pretty much need to have a "contract" in place that allows you to know the type of data to expect back.  Even if the data type (text, JSON, or XML) were to change, there would be no guarantee that even if normalized to the same data type, that the information returned in each would be the same (different schemas, etc.).  So pretty much, I think you need to design this on a request-by-request basis.

Comment: @ziesemer- OK, thank you... Currently I am getting the above response as plain text response...can you advice me on a way to extract the various values from the sample response I have given above? This being a plain text response...Thanks...

Comment: Without seeing your code, it sounds like you are receiving this as a plain text response (maybe even mistakenly having a Content-Type of "text/plain") - but it is clearly JSON.  Use GSON or another similar library to parse this into a Java object tree format that you would be able to more-easily work with.